# How to determine and use a given number of questions from an array? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, shuffle

I have a String[] array of 300+ questions. When I start my "Test Activity" it creates a test with the "whole" lenght of the array (300). However, I would like to use only 115 questions (randomly) from that array. Is this possible to do?

This is my loop code, which I assume is the responsible for the quantity of questions used.?

```
 //This is my FOR Loop

 public void shuffleChapterRandomTest() {
    shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest = new String[chapterRandomTestQuestions.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest.length; k++) {
        shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[k] = String.valueOf(k);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest));
    Log.i("TAG", "shuffle: " + shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[0] + " " + shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest[1]);
}
```

Comment: You're already shuffling it. Just select the first 115 and you should be good.

Comment: I'm sorry to sound dumb , but , how do I select those 115. I mean, I know is already shuffling so I already get the questions in random order. But don't know how to get only 115 instead of the 300. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but I think all your shuffled array does is hold a String value of an index, rather than the question.  It can be simplified if `chapterRandomTestQuestions` is that array of string questions.

Create a random list of `Strings` from the array and return the shuffled questions that can be iterated over as necessary :

```
 public List<String> shuffleChapterRandomTest() {
    final List<String> randomQuestions = Arrays.asList(chapterRandomTestQuestions);
    Collections.shuffle(randomQuestions);
    return randomQuestions.subList(0, 115);
}
```

This assumes there are greater than 115 items in the list, so a little unsafe (you could return `randomQuestions.subList(0, Math.min(chapterRandomTestQuestions.length, 115))` to stop this issue), otherwise it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`